# Sharing: Give mobile device homegroup access (but no more than that)

Tags: windows-7, networking, permissions, android, file-sharing

I'm accessing shared files on a windows 7 machine from an android.

This seems to be the recommended approach: [How to Add an Android Phone or Tablet to a Homegroup in Windows 7 and Windows 8](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/275503-homegroup-add-android-phone-tablet.html)
 and [Share files between Android and Windows with ES File Explorer](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57583739-285/share-files-between-android-and-windows-with-es-file-explorer/).

Basically from the file explorer in my android I can see my computer. I then can log on using my windows username and password and see all the files that are shared with me ("User: Me; Permission Level: (owner)").

I can see folders that are shared with "me" rather than home-group. I can't seem to unshare folders with "me" using windows explorer, I suspect all Libraries folders (documents, pictures etc) have to be shared with "me".

**Question: (Android and Windows)**
This there any way to connect with only home-group level permissions?

**Secondary question: (Windows)** Is there any way to unshare Libraries from "me" (the owner) or, even better, is there a way of forbidding this remote access so that the only way to access with "me" permission is to physically be at the computer?

Comment: What about creating a dummy user, which will be sharing with the android device, so that everything shared to that dummy user is accessible to the android device, but no more?

Comment: It's a good idea, as far as my main question goes. I suspect that you might be suggesting the only real way, but it's not at all tidy. I'm still quite interested in how I might limit sharing to remote users who know the machine's windows login info without cutting off home-group.

Comment: Te dummy user can be in the home group, you just need to be careful on what is shared to the home-group, or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: Not at all. Thanks for your suggestion it really is a good one.

Comment: I ll add this as answer, so you can close the question if nobody come with a better solution. I ll go in more details to be more generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment:

Create a dummy user, which is in the home-group, so that the device cannot access directly the computer (you can remove almost all right it have, at least don t make it administrator).

Better would be a group for it and the main user only so you can choose what to share in a easier way.

If you add it in the home-group, just be careful in what in shared in the homegroup and what is not, so it cannot access something else without physical access.